# Using ASP.NET, setup a component to redirect response for any HTTP requests

Tags: asp.net, iis

The objective of this component is to be able to forward whatever HTTP requests it receives to forward to a different server based on the parameters but keeping the URL and POST data intact.  For example:

If the component receives

```
http://sourceserver/XYZ.aspx?id=100
```

It will return the response from either

```
http://targetserverONE/XYZ.aspx?id=100
http://targetserverTWO/XYZ.aspx?id=100
```

where XYZ can be valid name of the page.  I think I can probably individually create each page to do a Response.Redirect but i am wondering if there is a more generic way to do this?  In addition, is this something I have to configure on the IIS level rather than code level?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in IIS from IIS Manager:

[IIS 6 Instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true)
[IIS 7 Instructions](http://forums.iis.net/t/1157468.aspx)

**Edit:**
Just re-read your question and realize you're load balancing between two servers.  You can do this at the administrative level as well.  [Google load balancing](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=IIS+load+balancing)